# Figure numbering removing section LyX

Tags: floats, numbering, lyx

Figures are labeled as 1.0.1 but as I am only using "Parts" and do not have "chapters" or"sections" i would like them to be 1.1, 1.2 and so on.

Comment: Further more they should be labeled with the parts... 2.1 2.2 and so on

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example so people can understand your setup.

Comment: It is a report (KOMA - Script). I've added "\setcounter{chapter}{1}" to get the numbers to start at one and not zero. I am using parts and unnumbered sections but not chapters. There are 3 parts in the document, each with (say) 3 figures. The figures are labeled 1.0.1 to 1.0.9 where I would like them to be as follows: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{figure}{part}% Reset figure numbering at every part
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{figure}}% Figure number is part.figure
```

The default numbering of parts in [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) is Roman, so I've used `\arabic{part}` since. However, if you've updated this somehow to be Roman elsewhere, you could just use `\thepart.\arabic{figure}`.

Comment: This is so close. The only problem now is that there is an extra period following the number. So it reads "1.1." which would be fine except there is an additional colon following it so it looks funny (1.1.:). Thanks!

Comment: @user48857: You may wish to add `\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{\figurename~\thefigure}` to your LaTeX Preamble as well. This redefinition removes the default `\autodot` that follows `\thefigure`. Depending on your preference, you may not like the inconsistency between how the figure number is displayed in the actual float compared to the LoF, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have figures numbered not following sectionning ! fig1 fig2 fig3!

And what you are getting is fig 0.1, fig 0.2 ...

Then what you need to do is to make sure the `Number figures by section` is not used in document > settings > modules!

And too use document class **article (standard)**.

(on document > settings > document class)

The numbering will turn nice! Continous without sectionning!